# Error in running latex file with chemgreek.sty

Tags: mhchem

I'm trying to compile my Latex file but I'm getting the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> Chem\str_uppercase:f
{\tl_head:n {alpha}}\str_lowercase:f {\tl_ta...
l.584 \chemgreek_drop_symbols:
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

As I'm new to latex, I'm unable to fix the error in the chemgreek.sty file. So, if anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

Comment: You need to update your TeX distribution. Your version of `chemgreek` is newer than the packages it depends on

Comment: @cgnieder, I upgraded the Texmaker. But it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: texmaker is your editor. I am talking about the *tex distribution* (MiKTeX or texlive most likely).

Comment: While updating texlive, I got a message that the Tex Live 2018 is frozen forever. So what can I do now?

Comment: The current texlive is texlive 2020, see https://www.tug.org/texlive/